# How do I cut off first bits in an unsigned long with bitwise?

Tags: c, hex, bitwise-operators

I have `m = 0x401e000000000000` and I want to get `f = 0xe000000000000`. Using bitwise operators, how would I do that in C?
I used
`f = (m & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF);`

but I just get 0.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Compiler error? Incorrect result?

Comment: That should work. Maybe the problem is with how you're showing the result. Please post a [mre].

Comment: https://ideone.com/mFBSI9

Comment: Okay. I'm dumb. I wasn't printing it right.

Comment: `unsigned long` may only be 32- bit.  For this "I want to get f = 0xe000000000000", better to use `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 2):

When run in [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/mFBSI9), it works

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned long m = 0x401e000000000000;
  unsigned long f = m & (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF); // Expect value = 0xe000000000000.
  
  printf("Result f = 0x%0lX\n", f);
  
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5416KB
Result f = 0xE000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the `>>` `<<` operators, the "12" in the code is the bit positions you you want to shift.
The `<<` operator shifts its left-hand operand left by the number of bits defined by its right-hand operand.
The left-shift operation discards the high-order bits that are outside the range of the result type and sets the low-order empty bit positions to zero, then you can use the `>>` operand to restore the scale.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long m = 0x401e000000000000;
    m = (m<<12);
    m = (m>>12);

    printf("Result f = 0x%0lX\n", m);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `m<<12` is unclear.  Why shift left for OP? Why shift 12?

Comment: You're right, I correct my answer Thanks!